# Layout error with admob banner, set size programmatically

Tags: android, layout, size, admob, adview

[image]
[image]

```
       <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
           >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu1"
            android:layout_width="75dip"
            android:layout_height="74dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/menu1"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu2"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/menu2"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu3"
            android:layout_width="75dip"
            android:layout_height="63dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/menu3"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu4"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="83dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/menu4"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>

              <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                   android:layout_marginTop="200dp">

 <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu5"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/menu5" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu6"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="79dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/menu6"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu7"
            android:layout_width="60dip"
            android:layout_height="86dip"
           android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/menu7"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu8"
            android:layout_width="75dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:layout_marginRight="110dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/menu8" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
         </TableRow>

                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                    android:layout_marginTop="190dp">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/menu9"
                        android:layout_width="60px"
                        android:layout_height="80px"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/menu9"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu10"
            android:layout_width="75dip"
            android:layout_height="56dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/menu10" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu11"
            android:layout_width="75dip"
            android:layout_height="65dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/menu11"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu12"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/menu12" />
  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**12-17 15:39:36.167: I/Ads(1495): onReceiveAd()
12-17 15:39:36.198: W/Ads(1495): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <320, 50>, Has: <320, 0>**

this layout looks ok on eclipse but when I run it every thing go missy ! and I am really bad in designs and layout , so how to set the size of the adview banner programmatically ?

Comment: can u add some screenshots?

Answer (score 3):

Try to add a width and a height for your banner view:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="..."
    ads:loadAdsOnCreate="true" />
```

---

EDIT: Maybe your problem is that there's no left space in your layout. So my approach would be to use a RelativeLayout in top of your xml like this:

```
RelativeLayout

   TableLayout

   AdView
```

Instead of having your adView inside the TableLayout.

Comment: no this was not the solution but I will vote ur answer up for ur effort

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper please mark the answer as correct if you solved the problem ;)